# how to apply filters to typeahead in angular

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, typeahead

I have typeahead in my event mgmt form.Used factory for data. I save invited members to an array.
 On next selection of member,I dont need to get already selected member name in the autosuggest.

Plz guide with using filters.

Using javascript, I know to compare and can  restrict user from entering duplicate entry into my array.